# remove(Object key) for a Sorted Binary Tree

Tags: java, sorting, tree, binary

I'm tasked to implement a remove() method for my Sorted Binary Tree. I need to pass a set of tests which was assigned by our teacher, and I'm struggling to do so. This is the code I have currently, which was heavily borrowed from our schoolbook.

```
@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public V remove(Object key) throws NoSuchElementException {
    if(!containsKey((K) key)){
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }

    ReturnObject oldEntry = new ReturnObject(null);
    SortedTreeMap<K, V> newRoot = removeEntry(getRoot(this), (K) key, oldEntry);

    if(newRoot != null){
        setRoot(newRoot.data);
        setLeftChild(newRoot.leftChild);
        setRightChild(newRoot.rightChild);
    } else{
        this.data = null;
    }

    if(oldEntry.get() != null){
        size--;
    }


    return oldEntry.get();
}

/*
*   Removes the entry in a given root node of a subtree.
*   rootNode is the root node of the subtree.
*   Returns the root node of the revised subtree.
*
* */
private SortedTreeMap<K,V> removeFromRoot(SortedTreeMap<K, V> rootNode){
    if(rootNode.hasLeftChild() && rootNode.hasRightChild()){
        SortedTreeMap<K,V> leftSubtreeRoot = rootNode.getLeftChild();
        SortedTreeMap<K,V> largestNode = findLargest(leftSubtreeRoot);

        rootNode.setRoot(largestNode.getRoot());

        rootNode.setLeftChild(removeLargest(leftSubtreeRoot));
    } else if(rootNode.hasRightChild()) {
        rootNode = rootNode.getRightChild();
    } else{
        rootNode = rootNode.getLeftChild();
    }
    return rootNode;
}

/*
*   Finds the node containing the largest entry in a given tree.
*   rootNode is the root node of the tree.
*   Returns the node containing the largest entry in the tree.
*
* */
private SortedTreeMap<K,V> findLargest(SortedTreeMap<K, V> rootNode){
    if(rootNode.hasRightChild()){
        rootNode = findLargest(rootNode.getRightChild());
    }
    return rootNode;
}

/*
*   Removes the node containing the largest entry in a given tree.
*   rootNode is the root node of the tree.
*   Returns the root node of the revised tree.
*
* */
private SortedTreeMap<K,V> removeLargest(SortedTreeMap<K, V> rootNode){
    if(rootNode.hasRightChild()){
        SortedTreeMap<K,V> rightEntry = rootNode.getRightChild();
        rightEntry = removeLargest(rightEntry);
        rootNode.setRightChild(rightEntry);
    } else{
        rootNode = rootNode.getLeftChild();
    }
    return rootNode;
}

/*
*   Removes an entry from the tree rooted at a given node.
*   rootNode is a reference to the root of a tree.
*   entry is the object to be removed.
*   oldEntry is an object whose data field is null
*   Returns the root node of the resulting tree; if entry matches
*        an entry in the tree, oldEntry's data field is the entry
*        that was removed from the tree; otherwise it is null.
*       */
private SortedTreeMap<K,V> removeEntry(SortedTreeMap<K,V> rootNode, K entry, ReturnObject oldEntry){
    if(rootNode != null){
        K rootData = rootNode.data.key;
        int comparison = entry.compareTo(rootData);

        if(comparison == 0){
            oldEntry.set(rootNode.data.value);
            rootNode = removeFromRoot(rootNode);
        } else if(comparison < 0){
            SortedTreeMap<K,V> leftEntry = rootNode.getLeftChild();
            SortedTreeMap<K,V> subtreeRoot = removeEntry(leftEntry, entry, oldEntry);
            rootNode.setLeftChild(subtreeRoot);
        } else{
            SortedTreeMap<K,V> rightEntry = rootNode.getRightChild();
            rootNode.setRightChild(removeEntry(rightEntry, entry, oldEntry));
        }
    }
    return rootNode;
}
```

And this is the test I'm struggling to pass:

```
/**
 * Check that entry is no longer in map after remove
 */
public Property remove_removes_entry() {
    return property(isKVList,
            kvs -> implies(kvs.length() > 0,
                    () -> property(choose(0, kvs.length()-1),
                            i -> {
                                P2<Integer, String> entry = kvs.index(i);

                                SortedTreeMap<Integer, String> tm = new SortedTreeMap<>(intOrd.toComparator());
                                kvs.foreachDoEffect(kv -> tm.add(kv._1(), kv._2()));

                                tm.remove(entry._1());
                                List<Integer> keys = fromIterator(tm.keys().iterator());
                                return prop(!keys.exists(key -> key.equals(entry._1())));
                            })
            )
    );
}
```

The error message I'm getting is this:

> java.lang.Error: Falsified after 2 passed tests with arguments:
>   List(List((0,gzprxt),(4,lntpqj),(-5,caki),(-6,jzf)),2)

I can get in between 0 to 60 passes and I don't get which scenario the remove method fails in. I've tried to make a Junit test, but didn't succeed.

Here is some more context for my class:

```
public class Entry<K, V> {
public final K key;
public final V value;

public Entry(K key, V value) {
    this.key = key;
    this.value = value;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof Entry) {
        Entry other = (Entry)o;
        return this.key.equals(other.key) && this.value.equals(other.value);
    }
    return false;
}
}


public class SortedTreeMap<K extends Comparable<? super K>, V> implements ISortedTreeMap<K, V> {

private int size;
private Entry<K,V> data;
private SortedTreeMap<K,V> leftChild, rightChild, parent;
private Comparator<K> keyComparator;

private SortedTreeMap(K key, V value, Comparator<K> keyComparator, SortedTreeMap<K, V> parent){
    data = new Entry<>(key, value);
    this.parent = parent;
    this.keyComparator = keyComparator;
}

public SortedTreeMap(Comparator<K> kComparator) {
    keyComparator = kComparator;
}

private Entry<K,V> getRoot(){
    return this.data;
}

private SortedTreeMap<K,V> getLeftChild(){
    return this.leftChild;
}

private SortedTreeMap<K,V> getRightChild(){
    return this.rightChild;
}

private void setLeftChild(SortedTreeMap<K, V> newLeftChild){
    leftChild = newLeftChild;
}

private void setRightChild(SortedTreeMap<K, V> newRightChild){
    rightChild = newRightChild;
}

private void setRoot(Entry<K, V> newRoot){
    data = newRoot;
}

private boolean hasLeftChild(){
    return leftChild != null;
}

private boolean hasRightChild(){
    return rightChild != null;
}

@Override
public V add(K key, V value) {
    V result = null;

    if(isEmpty()) {
        data = new Entry<>(key, value);
    } else{
        int comparison = keyComparator.compare(key, data.key);
        SortedTreeMap<K,V> newChild = new SortedTreeMap<>(key, value, keyComparator, this);

        if(comparison < 0){
            if (hasLeftChild()) {
                result = leftChild.add(key, value);
            } else{
                setLeftChild(newChild);
            }

        } else if(comparison > 0){
            if (hasRightChild()) {
                result = rightChild.add(key, value);
            } else{
                setRightChild(newChild);
            }
        } else{
            result = data.value;
            this.data = new Entry<>(key, value);
        }
    }
    if (result == null){
        size++;
    }
    return result;
}

@Override
public Iterable<K> keys() {
    return new KeyIterator(this);
}

public class KeyIterator implements Iterable<K>, Iterator<K>{
    private SortedTreeMap<K,V> next;

    KeyIterator(SortedTreeMap<K, V> root){
        next = root;

        while(next.leftChild != null){
            next = next.leftChild;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<K> iterator() {
        return this;
    }

    public boolean hasNext(){
        return next != null && !next.isEmpty();
    }

    public K next(){
        if(!hasNext()){
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
        SortedTreeMap<K,V> r = next;

        if(next.rightChild != null){
            next = next.rightChild;
            while(next.leftChild != null){
                next = next.leftChild;
            }
            return r.data.key;
        }

        while(true){
            if(next.parent == null){
                next = null;
                return r.data.key;
            }

            if(next.parent.leftChild == next){
                next = next.parent;
                return r.data.key;
            }
            next = next.parent;
        }
    }
}
```